# Getting empty result from the @Query in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, spring-boot, psql

I am using Hibernate to execute my query, in admin panel i am getting correct result but while using in Hibernate it is not giving any result.

Dao layer -

```
@Query("select new com.eventila.pms.entity.ReferenceLead(projectId,count(lm)) from LeadMaster lm where lm.vendorId= ?1 and lm.source = 'share' group by lm.projectId")
List<ReferenceLead> getReferenceByUser(String userId);
```

Pojo -

```
@lombok.Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class ReferenceLead {

    String projectId;
    Long referenceLead;
    Long count;

    protected ReferenceLead(){}


    public ReferenceLead(String projectId,Long count) {
        this.projectId=projectId;
        this.count=count;
    }

}
```

After executing this i am getting a empty list.
Please help me out.

Comment: Please add your `LeadMaster` entity to the question,.

Answer (score 0):

In your select query return the fields without calling new constructor:

```
@Query("select projectId, count(lm) from LeadMaster lm where lm.vendorId = ?1 and lm.source = 'share' group by lm.projectId")
List<ReferenceLead> getReferenceByUser(String userId);
```

Hibernate will instantiate the object using these fields. Also, add @Entity annotation to your ReferenceLead class.

Comment: if i will use entity annotation then i have to mention the table name right? but it is a pojo only not associated to any table

Answer (score 0):

'source' is the keyword in SQL.

It is a keyword used in MERGE. i.e. WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE.

The word MATCHED also exhibits the same behaviour in that it gets highlighted grey in the editor.

Neither of these are reserved keywords though so if used as an identifier they do not need to be delimited (unless you find the syntax highlighting distracting).

Comment: can you please tell me the solution? actually i am unable to get your ans

Comment: In your query you have 'lm.source' which is a reserved word in SQL. Try changing field to some other same.

Comment: It means that you may try renaming source field from LeadMaster table, as it is a reserved word in PostgreSQL and MySQL.